# How should I model pathfinding in the object oriented paradigm

Tags: oop, path-finding

My goal is to implement a (very simple) strategy game.

For the moment, I'll start with the map and two characters (I want the terrain to affect them differently) to experiment with pathfinding

The problem is that I have very little or no experience in object oriented design. I've used C++ classes before, but it was pretty straightforward: for instance, a class Graph implemented using an array of sets, with a method AStar. I didn't have in mind the concept of "several players".

I've thought of the following elements/classes:  Game, Map and Character. Eventually a Pathfinder class.

**First question**: the position of a character is something the game should know? The map? or each character?

( I think the game should )

**Second question**: where would it be a good choice for a "findPath" method?

- The Game?
- Should a pathfinding algorithm be a method of Map? Something like map.findPath(character, srcpos, dstpos)
- In the Character class? It makes more sense to do character1.findPath(map, srcpos, dstpos)
- If I added a Pathfinder class, it would have to build its own representation of the map in order to determine the shortest path. And before doing that, it would have "to ask" the map how the terrain affects each player.

( I prefer the latter )

It seems the construction of an auxiliary structure (and asking the map) to apply, let's say, A* is something that I can't avoid.

Answer (score 2):

Making things object-oriented is not a goal, it's a tool to be used when it makes sense. C++ is a language with lots of functionality that you can easily drown yourself with, so my advice is to keep things simple and easy.

This can mean keeping data and logic tightly together sometimes, or separating it completely other times.

First question: My initial reaction is that the character should know its position. But how you represent it with data depends on how you intend to use it, so both the game, the character and potentially also the map needs to know where the character is.

Second question: It depends on what the Map class is. Is it an object representing the map itself with necessary functionality exposed to the rest of your program, or is it a toolbox of functions that works on a simple data representation of the map?

If the Map class represents the map, it should have the necessary functionality exposed for a Pathfinder class to work on it (the pathfinding algorithm will need to have some additional data derived from the map, maybe temporary, maybe persistent).

If the Map class does not represent the map, you can put the pathfinding functionality in it. I think it would belong there in that case. If the pathfinding code causes the Map class to get too big, you should separate it into its own class anyway.

Answer (score 1):

First Question: The position of the character should be a part of character itself (makes sense this way) for me.

Second Question: Finding a path logically cannot be a part of Map. Then you would be **violating** one of **OOP principles** i.e. **Single Responsibility**.

According to me you should create the PathFinder class. You can design it in this way

```
class PathFinder{
      PathFinderAlgorithm algorithm;
      //other required values according to your design

      Path findPath(){
          algorithm.apply();
      }

      //other required methods according to your design

}
```

`PathFinderAlgorithm` is an interface.
Using this you can also change the algorithm that you are using to find the path. Like if you in future need to find the longest path, all you have to do is create another class which will find the longest path and replace it in the PathFinder class.